# devtools::install(): Installing R package which imports another package that is stored locally

Tags: r, dependencies, installation, devtools

I am trying to build R packages locally simply to standardize my code for my own benefit. I've no intention to post on CRAN or GitHub. What I would like to do is import packages I've already developed into a new package I'm developing.

For example:

- call the first package ***pack_a*** and the second package
  ***pack_b***.
- ***pack_a*** does not have any dependencies and installs without any issues.
- ***pack_b*** is dependent on ***pack_a*** so ***pack_a*** is referenced in the DESCRIPTION file of ***pack_b*** under the imports tag.

The problem I'm facing is that when I install pack_b (using `devtools::install()`) the following error comes up:

```
Skipping 1 unavailable package: pack_a
```

After looking through the [code of devtools on GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/deps.R) it appears that it is looking on CRAN for the required packages using `available.packages()`. Of course my ***pack_a*** is not on CRAN so it fails to find it and then ***pack_b*** fails to install. I was hoping it would first check if ***pack_a*** is already installed in my default library and therefore not even try to re-install it.

So my question comes down to:

How do I specify where to find ***pack_a*** on my local drive when installing ***pack_b***? And if that's not possible is there a switch to turn off installation of required packages during install?

A similar question was asked before and I'm not entirely sure but I think one of the suggestions was to add your local path to the `repos` argument of `install.packages()`. This did not work for me however.

Previous similar question: [R package which imports SparkR (not on CRAN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971110/r-package-which-imports-sparkr-not-on-cran)

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use `repos` arg to your local directory you need to create expected dir structure, [drat](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat) package will help you with it.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem using `utils::install.packages`?

Comment: @jangorecki, thanks for the pointer to drat. This will be useful for the future. It turns my issue had nothing to do with dependencies but in fact was because i had a file with the same name as my package saved in my library (not sure how it got there...) so feeling kind of stupid for asking the question now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you are having this issue without more details, as I do exactly as you describe for my own packages (both also *not* on CRAN) and have no issues.

Having said that, a simple solution if you know for sure that `pack_a` is installed *before* you install `pack_b` is to run:

```
devtools::install(dependencies = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If in fact the reason it was failing was the dependency issue this would be the correct answer so i'll accept it.

In actual fact i was wrongly attributing that warning as the reason it was failing to install. It was actually failing because i had a file in my library with the same name as my package, therefore it couldn't create a new directory with the same name.

I should have done more investigation before asking the question but thanks anyway, good to know this for future reference.

Comment: @Yabasa, when you say "a file in my library with the same name as my package", do you mean a directory? And was the name `pack_a` or `pack_b`? I'm getting the same `Skipping 1 unavailable package: local_packages_already_installed` error. Trying to figure out if I have the same cause of the error. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh It was a file and it was called pack_a. I'm not sure how it got there but i must have accidentally created it at some point.

Comment: Thanks. Was the pack_a file in your main R lib location (C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\library on my Windows machine), or a local/personal (sorry, not sure of the terminology) library? I get the same error, though my installation succeeds.