# R package dependencies not installed from Additional_repositories (revisited)

Tags: r, cran, submission

I am attempting to prepare a package for submission to the CRAN. In my DESCRIPTION file I include non-CRAN packages in the Depends and Suggests arguments. To tell R where to find the non-CRAN packages, I include the Additional_repositories argument; and I include an .onLoad function at the top of my program (i.e., in 'zzz.R'). I am able to build and check (--as-cran) in RStudio with zero warnings, notes or errors so long as all the Depends and Suggests packages are present. I then use devtools::build() to create a .tar.gz file locally.

To test for a successful local install, I remove the non-CRAN packages from my computer and attempt to install the .tar.gz file that I created. I then get the message:

```
ERROR: dependency 'smwrQW' is not available for package 'baytrends'
```

I've read through the

- [R package dependencies not installed from Additional_repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419776/r-package-dependencies-not-installed-from-additional-repositories)
- [Include non-CRAN package in CRAN package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335321/include-non-cran-package-in-cran-package)
- http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-data-packages-in-external-data-repositories-using-the-additional_repositories-field/
- [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Unfortunately, the above error continues. I'm confident of the url I'm using since the below install.package line works when run independently

```
install.packages('smwrQW',repos=c("http://owi.usgs.gov/R"),dependencies = TRUE)
```

The applicable bits of the DESCRIPTION and zzz.R file are below:

DESCRIPTION:

```
Date: 2017-03-15
Depends:
    R (>= 3.2.0),
    lubridate,
    mgcv,
    smwrQW
License: GPL-3
LazyData: TRUE
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
Suggests:
    dataRetrieval,
    devtools,
    fitdistrplus,
    knitr,
    nlme,
    pander,
    plyr,
    rmarkdown,
    smwrBase,
    smwrGraphs,
    smwrStats,
    testthat
Additional_repositories: http://owi.usgs.gov/R
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

zzz.R:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname = find.package("baytrends"), pkgname = "baytrends"){

  repos = getOption("repos")
  repos["USGS"] = "http://owi.usgs.gov/R"
  options(repos = repos)
  invisible(repos)

  # declaration of global variables (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256)
  if(getRversion() >= "2.15.1")
    utils::globalVariables(c("begin", "methodsList"))
  invisible()

}

.onAttach <-  function(libname = find.package("baytrends"), pkgname = "baytrends"){
  packageStartupMessage("This software program is preliminary or provisional and is subject to revision. ")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *cannot* have packages from non-standard repos in Depends: or Imports:.

You *can* have them in Suggests:

Several packages do this; one you could look at is [hurricaneexposure](https://cran.r-project.org/package=hurricaneexposure) which uses this to make a 'too-large-for-CRAN' data package [hurricanexposuredata](https://github.com/geanders/hurricaneexposuredata) available from a [repository](https://github.com/geanders/drat/tree/gh-pages/src/contrib) created via [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html).

So you *must* move the smwrQR package to Suggests: and then test for it.

Brooke and I have a draft paper (under review) on this which we could send you if you drop us line -- it details all this more than the short answer could.

Comment: Thanks. I moved smwrQW to Suggests: and got a "Namespace dependencies not required : 'smwrQW'" error. I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085481/namespace-dependencies-not-required and moved smwrQW to Imports: . this corrected the build error but left me at same place as original posting.

Comment: You also need to remove it from NAMESPACE.  No Depends, no Imports, no NAMESPACE -- only Suggests.

Comment: I created some other errors. Will restart on a test package and implement your recommendations.